# Volleyball rules for edit review

Tags: discussion, feature-request

To win in volleyball, team has to win 3 sets. So the match can end with set score **3:0**, **3:1** or **3:2**.
So volleyball match is similar to suggested edit review process. You have to gather 3 approvals to 'win' (I am omitting 'Reject and edit' and 'Accept and Edit' options here). But when we continue this analogy we will se a difference.

When volleyball match is played in group phase then points are assigned for every game. When the team wins **3:0** or **3:1** it gains 3 points. And when it wins **3:2** it gains only 2 points (third point is for a looser). So big victories are favoured.

On Stackoverflow you get 2 points for every approved edit. It doesn't matter if it was approved with no rejection or if it had 2 rejection votes.

But imagine we adapt scoring rules from volleyball to review process. So the user should receive:

- 2 points when edit was accepted without rejection votes
- 1 point when it was accepted with one rejection vote
- 0 votes (or 1) when accepted with 2 rejection votes

Such system seems fair to me. Rejection votes indicate that there was something wrong with this edit and maybe it is not worth whole award. The advantages of such system:

- It would change (for better) behavior of several bad editers
- Now voting for 'Reject' in most cases doesn't change anything. Bad edits are mostly approved anyhow by bad reviewers. So this system would slightly decrease frustration of good thorough reviewers.

Only disadvantage I see is that bad editors would do more bad edits to recompensate the loss from rejected (and partially rejected) edits.

This post is based on my experience. There were times when I was:

- poor editer
- good editer
- poor reviewer
- good reviewer

What do you think of above idea?

**EDIT**

Answering to critic:

> Rep gained from suggested edits should be based on net outcome of user decisions, not individual user decisions.

In current system not always result is based on net outcome. Sometimes it is based on individual decision. While reviewing you have two options:

- Reject and Edit
- Improve

First causes immediate rejection and second causes immediate acceptance. So you can with one move cause rejection of edit which already has two 'Accept' votes.

> Additionally, I think 2 rep for a net decision of "Accept" is the minimum we should earn really.

Sometimes I see edits which remove only 'Thank you' from post. It may be correct edit but is not worth 2 points.

Comment: *Only disadvantage I see is that bad editors would do more bad edits to recompensate the loss from rejected (and partially rejected) edits.* You're absolutely right. This would scale for the worst. That's why we can't have nice things.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**
Rep gained from suggested edits should be based on *net outcome* of user decisions, not *individual* user decisions.

---

---

> 2 points when edit was accepted without rejection votes
> 1 point when it was accepted with one rejection vote
> 0 votes (or 1) when accepted with 2 rejection votes
>
> Such system seems fair to me

I disagree.

The point of community voting and reviewing is it allows for *varied* opinions and decisions about a scenario to *converge* to only **one** of two outcomes (accept/reject).
And I believe rep should be allocated based on the same fair and single outcome.

There will often be *individual* users who disagree with one-another - eg on the same review, some accept and some reject.

So with your scheme:
Those *individual* users might not be good at reviewing, have had a bad day, or robo review, etc.
So now the individuals make a difference to what rep you receive as we'd no longer get rep based on a single end result of *net votes*, but *individual* user votes.

We'd end up with "*pot-luck*" as to whether we obtain 0, 1, or 2 points, because of those *individual* opinions.

Which is why I think it's important that rep is gained based on that **single** *net* outcome.

---

Additionally, I think 2 rep for a net decision of "Accept" is the minimum we should earn really. If users obtained 1 rep or even 0 because they only got X approves and Y rejects, then meta would be inundated with questions debating individual user decisions on their suggested edits.